# Where is the .psqlrc file on Windows?

Tags: postgresql

I tried following the advice on https://mladenuzelac.blogspot.com/2016/01/psqlrc-in-windows.html to find it, but there is no postgresql folder under C:\Users\My_Username\AppData\Roaming. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then create it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following Laurenz advice, I simply created the folder `%APPDATA%\postgresql` and added a `psqlrc.conf` file, and it worked like a charm.